# Complex algebraic submersions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be smooth complex algebraic varieties and let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Z$ be two morphisms. Suppose that $f$ is surjective, that $df_x:T_xX\to T_{f(x)}Y$ is surjective for all $x\in X$ (i.e. $f$ is a holomorphic submersion), and that $g$ is constant on the fibres of $f$. Then, in the analytic category, there is a unique holomorphic map $h:Y\to Z$ such that $h\circ f=g$.
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X &\\
\downarrow & \searrow\\
Y & \xrightarrow{} & Z\end{array}$$
Is $h$ also a morphism of complex algebraic varieties? If yes, any reference?

Comment: The morphism $f$ is fppf (faithfully flat and finitely presented).  For a morphism $g:X\to Z$ such that the two induced morphisms on $X\times_Y X$ are equal, there exists a unique morphism $h:Y\to Z$ such that $g$ equals $h\circ f$ by "fppf descent".  Since $X\times_Y X$ is smooth (by your hypothesis), equality of the two induced morphisms is a pointwise condition, and it is equivalent to your hypothesis that $g$ is constant on fibers of $f$.